# GetOption PERL to Python

Tags: python-2.7, perl

How would I write this PERL line in python?

```
GetOptions('help|?' => \$help, 'man' => \$man, 'debug!' => \$debug, 'devpath:s' => \$devpath, 'dev2:s' => \$dev2,'rev1:s' => \$prj_rev1, 'rev2:s' => \$prj_rev2, 'prj:s' => \$prj)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a module in python called `argparse`. You can use the module to solve your problem.

Code example : **test.py**

```
import argparse
import os

commandLineArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-fname", "--fname",  help="first name")
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-lname","--lname", help="last name")
commandLineArguments = commandLineArgumentParser.parse_args()

fname = commandLineArguments.fname
lname = commandLineArguments.lname

print "%s\n%s" %(fname,lname)
```

Run example

```
python test.py -fname ms -lname = dhoni
```

Output

```
ms
dhoni
```